# Using JsonSchemaForm on change to update field's content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

I am trying to use JsonSchema-Form component but i ran into a problem while trying to create a form that, after choosing one of the options in the first dropdown a secondary dropdown should appear and give him the user a different set o options to choose depending on what he chose in the first dropdown trough an API call.

The thing is, after reading the documentation and some examples found [here](https://github.com/RxNT/react-jsonschema-form-extras) and [here](https://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/) respectively i still don't know exactly how reference whatever i chose in the first option to affect the second dropdown. Here is an example of what i have right now:

Jsons information that are supposed to be shown in the first and second dropdowns trough api calls:

```
Groups: [
{id: 1,
name: Group1}
{id: 2,
name: Group2}
]
User: [User1.1,User1.2,User2.1,User2.2,User3.1,User3.2, ....]
```

If the user selects group one then i must use the following api call to get the user types, which gets me the the USER json.

Component That calls JSonChemaForm

```
render(){
 return(
          <JsonSchemaForm
            schema={someSchema(GroupOptions)}
            formData={this.state.formData}
            onChange={{}}
            uiSchema={someUiSchema()}
            onError={() => {}}
            showErrorList={false}
            noHtml5Validate
            liveValidate
          > 
 )
}
```

SchemaFile content:

```
export const someSchema = GroupOptions => ({
  type: 'object',
  required: [
    'groups', 'users',
  ],
  properties: {
    groups: {
      title: 'Group',
      enum: GroupOptions.map(i=> i.id),
      enumNames: GroupOptions.map(n => n.name),
    },
    users: {
      title: 'Type',
      enum: [],
      enumNames: [],
    },
  },
});

export const someUISchema = () => ({
  groups: {
    'ui:autofocus': true,
    'ui:options': {
      size: {
        lg: 15,
      },
    },
  },
  types: {
    'ui:options': {
      size: {
        lg: 15,
      },
    },
  },

});
```

I am not really sure how to proceed with this and hwo to use the Onchange method to do what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a solution for your problem.There is a similar demo that can solve it in [react-jsonschema-form-layout](https://github.com/audibene-labs/react-jsonschema-form-layout).
1. define the LayoutField,this is part of the demo in [react-jsonschema-form-layout](https://github.com/audibene-labs/react-jsonschema-form-layout).To make it easier for you,I post the code here. 
Create the layoutField.js.:

```
import React from 'react'
import ObjectField from 'react-jsonschema-form/lib/components/fields/ObjectField'
import { retrieveSchema } from 'react-jsonschema-form/lib/utils'
import { Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default class GridField extends ObjectField {
    state = { firstName: 'hasldf' }
    render() {
        const {
            uiSchema,
            errorSchema,
            idSchema,
            required,
            disabled,
            readonly,
            onBlur,
            formData
        } = this.props
        const { definitions, fields, formContext } = this.props.registry
        const { SchemaField, TitleField, DescriptionField } = fields
        const schema = retrieveSchema(this.props.schema, definitions)
        const title = (schema.title === undefined) ? '' : schema.title

        const layout = uiSchema['ui:layout']

        return (
            <fieldset>
                {title ? <TitleField
                    id={`${idSchema.$id}__title`}
                    title={title}
                    required={required}
                    formContext={formContext}/> : null}
                {schema.description ?
                    <DescriptionField
                        id={`${idSchema.$id}__description`}
                        description={schema.description}
                        formContext={formContext}/> : null}
                {
                    layout.map((row, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div className="row" key={index}>
                                {
                                    Object.keys(row).map((name, index) => {
                                        const { doShow, ...rowProps } = row[name]
                                        let style = {}
                                        if (doShow && !doShow({ formData })) {
                                            style = { display: 'none' }
                                        }
                                        if (schema.properties[name]) {
                                            return (
                                                <Col {...rowProps} key={index} style={style}>
                                                    <SchemaField
                                                        name={name}
                                                        required={this.isRequired(name)}
                                                        schema={schema.properties[name]}
                                                        uiSchema={uiSchema[name]}
                                                        errorSchema={errorSchema[name]}
                                                        idSchema={idSchema[name]}
                                                        formData={formData[name]}
                                                        onChange={this.onPropertyChange(name)}
                                                        onBlur={onBlur}
                                                        registry={this.props.registry}
                                                        disabled={disabled}
                                                        readonly={readonly}/>
                                                </Col>
                                            )
                                        } else {
                                            const { render, ...rowProps } = row[name]
                                            let UIComponent = () => null

                                            if (render) {
                                                UIComponent = render
                                            }

                                            return (
                                                <Col {...rowProps} key={index} style={style}>
                                                    <UIComponent
                                                        name={name}
                                                        formData={formData}
                                                        errorSchema={errorSchema}
                                                        uiSchema={uiSchema}
                                                        schema={schema}
                                                        registry={this.props.registry}
                                                    />
                                                </Col>
                                            )
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }</fieldset>
        )
    }
}
```

in the file, you can define doShow property to define whether to show another component.
Next.Define the isFilled function in JsonChemaForm

```
const isFilled = (fieldName) => ({ formData }) => (formData[fieldName] && formData[fieldName].length) ? true : false
```

Third,after you choose the first dropdown ,the second dropdown will show up

```
import LayoutField from './layoutField.js'
const  fields={
   layout: LayoutField
}
const uiSchema={
    "ui:field": 'layout',
    'ui:layout': [
        {
            groups: {
                'ui:autofocus': true,
                'ui:options': {
                   size: {
                      lg: 15,
                 },
              },
            }
        },
        {
            users: {
                'ui:options': {
                    size: {
                        lg: 15,
                    },
                },
                doShow: isFilled('groups')
            }
        }
    ]
}
...
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Form
                schema={schema}
                uiSchema={uiSchema}
                fields={fields}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: it only solves part of the entire problem. sadly i couldnt solve it by myself. if i ever find the answer i'll post it here. i'll give it a tumbs up though.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man I have changed my answer.And I think this will solve your problem.